# How to convert rtf and html into plain text on the server side

Tags: c#, html, parsing, rtf, text-processing

I need to process the bodies of incoming e-mails. They can come in plain text, HTML and RichText formats. I need to execute text matching algorithms on the body text but the HTML and RichText tags will confuse them. Is there a way to get the plain text data?

I'm looking for a way that could automatically parse both formats (like when I press F3 in Total commander and it will display the text in both HTML and RTF files).

A commercial solution is also an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should not be too hard. Just remove for HTML every <...> and for rtf the beginnings of the lines... Did you ever look into that files?

Comment: I did,and it is more complicated than you think. In HTML removing the tags only will reveal scripts and comments, which is not good.
As for RTF: accented characters in non-English languages are encoded so they must be decoded.

Answer (score 2):

for html, I would use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). For example,

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

foreach(var node in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToList())
{
    node.Remove();
}

var text = document.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

and for rtf, I would load it to RichTextBox and save as text.

Using IFilter interface (like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31944/Implementing-a-TextReader-to-extract-various-files))can be another option

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm developer of these libraries

Yes, the HTML may contain Unicode symbols, like a "&#XXX;" or "&quot;". Also, for example, if HTML has a table with 3 columns and 2 rows it would be good to see this result as tabular text:

1 2 3

4 5 6

Instead of "1 2 3 4 5 6".

These [.Net libraries can help you to convert HTML and RTF to Text](http://www.sautin.com/products/components/htmtortf/htmltortf_component_product_tour.php).

Sample #1 - convert HTML to Unicode Text:

```
        SautinSoft.HtmlToRtf h = new SautinSoft.HtmlToRtf();
        h.OutputFormat=SautinSoft.HtmlToRtf.eOutputFormat.TextUnicode;
        string text = h.ConvertString(htmlString);
```

Sample #2 - Convert RTF to Unicode Text:

```
        SautinSoft.RtfToHtml r = new SautinSoft.RtfToHtml();
        r.OutputFormat = SautinSoft.RtfToHtml.eOutputFormat.Text;
        string text = r.ConvertString(rtfString);
```